# Caching system like memcached but where I need to list what is in the cache

Tags: language-agnostic, caching, memcached

What's the best caching system/daemon that supports get, put, delete and list (memcached, I think, doesn't support list)

An example

I would like to use memcached for my caching solution but I'm stuck with the application design that I currently have which is that I cache  the following 3 URLs I need to always have different cache keys.  That stops me from just declaring a list of URL params with which I could generate a cache item for.

- /badappdesign?iod=3
- /badappdesign?iod=3&h=23
- /badappdesign?iod=3&dsfj=435&dasv=342

In this instance iod=3 has changed so I need to clear all the keys that contain iod=3

I currently cache to a db and have to do a fairly expensive like '%iod=3%'

what can help?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the '3' out of iod=3 and stick that into an integer column and index on that? That will be drastically less expensive.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I should have been more clear that we can't determine all of the key value pairs. Effectively we need to be able to cache on the full string.